Nativescript ns clean error. Giving error Unable to start Cleanup process. Error while reporting exception: Error: Unable to start Cleanup process
I am working on nativescript project version 8.7.2. Node version - 22.2.0.
Getting issue with command ns clean. ns build android or ns run android commands are not working.
ns clean error image
Not able to build the project fails with this issue.
It through errors Unable to start Cleanup process.
Error while reporting exception: Error: Unable to start Cleanup process
Tried clearing temp, npm cache, restarted laptop, cloned as new project, checked with new bash. Nothing worked. Please help
